# Apply css styles to layers in openlayers3 using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, openlayers-3

Define layers and styles using openlayers3 API. I need 2 apply css styles for layers.for that code is in below used

```
//applying styles for wms layer
var fill = new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgba(237, 26, 170, 0.82)'});
var stroke = new ol.style.Stroke({color: '#4A12ED',width: 1.25});
var text = new ol.style.Text({color: '#F21A6C'});

var styles = [new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
           fill: fill,
           stroke: stroke,
           radius: 5
     }),
     fill: fill,
     stroke: stroke,
})];

var wms = new ol.layer.Tile({
     source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
         title: "Population Density",
         url: 'http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/geoserver/wms',
         params: {LAYERS: 'gpw-v3:gpw-v3-population-density_2000'}
     }),
     style: styles
});

/*****************************************************************************/
//applying styles for unescap layer

var unescap = new ol.layer.Tile({
     source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
          url: 'http://203.159.29.11:8200/geoserver/unescap/wms?',
          params: {LAYERS: 'unescap:rg_di_any_all'}
     }),
     style: new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: '#319FD3',width: 1}),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgba(17, 224, 36, 0.66)'}),
          text: new ol.style.Text({
                font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: '#ff0'}),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: '#09C',width: 3})
          })
     })
});
```

but styles are not applied error messages are not available in console I want to know what is wrong with this code and how to apply styles properly.

Answer (score 0):

The ol3 styles are meant to be used for vector layers, not for WMS layers. But you could set the `styles`, `SLD` or `SLD_BODY` property manually in the `params` to set a style.